# Issue with dynamic pixels sampling in python in Nuke

Tags: python, frame, pixel, nuke

As a exercise I recently started scripting a little tool that generates lightnings between 2 geometries. Until now I succeeded in creating a random number of lightnings linked to the geos using mostly dynamic expressions created through a python script.

I want to add a few branches at the contact for each lightnings and the fastest way I found was to use the particle system to spread points on the destination geo. Using image processing and position pass I am able to quickly extract the point that are close to the lightnings contact points.

Now I have no other solution than to run a little script on each frame to put the segregated points position and index in a list for each frames.

I frequently face the same issue when it comes to sample pixels in loop in a python script. The frame does not update when using **nuke.frame()**.

This is the piece of script I am working on :

```
sn = nuke.thisNode()
snc = nuke.toNode('PosCP')

AllcontactAllFrame = []
AllcontactAllFrame[:] = []

AllcontactOnFrame = []
AllcontactOnFrame[:] = []

EachContactOnFrame = []
EachContactOnFrame[:] = []


def AppendContactLists( FirstFrame , LastFrame , wdth , hght):

  for fra in range (FirstFrame, LastFrame+1) :

    nuke.frame(fra)

    for h in range (0, hght) :
      for w in range (0, wdth) :

        Vpix = snc.sample('alpha', w, h)

        if Vpix == 1 :

          Contx = snc.sample('red', w , h)
          Conty = snc.sample('green', w, h)
          Contz = snc.sample('blue', w, h)

          PosC = [Contx,Conty,Contz]

          EachContactOnFrame.append(h)
          EachContactOnFrame.append(PosC)


width = snc.width()
height = snc.height()

ff = int(sn.knob('FirstFrameTmp').getValue())
lf = int(sn.knob('LastFrameTmp').getValue())

AppendContactLists(ff,lf,width,height)

nuke.message(str(EachContactOnFrame))
```

PosC should be stored with different values for each frames but it only stores the values of the first frame for each frames.

Does anyone have a workaround or this ?

Or does anyone knows a way to store none zeros pixels(in line for example) using something else than python ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this issues as being going around for years and The Foundry has not assessed it yet. I am using Nuke 10.5v1.

Comment: I am now using the dirty workaround of running a curvetool for each frame and it seems to be working